# Spring Boot Server Sometimes Just Doesn't Respond to Requests

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am building an API with Spring Boot and Kotlin and I am having a weird experience.

Whenever I am calling any of my built endpoints sometimes the server would never send back a response even though it is still up and running. It is not shutdown, there is no error it would just not send back any response.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Try to set logging level to DEBUG, maybe you will find something (add logging.level.root=DEBUG to application.properties). Also, can you post java thread dump when it's happening? There may be some deadlock.

Comment: It's really hard to answer your question 100% correctly without looking at some example. Could you please share your configuration, e.g. on github without any proprietary logic?

Comment: That's really hard to help with this set of details. Problem can be anywhere, from java code to infrastructure (kubernetes/aws/localhost ?). Please add as much details as possible. Start from your infrastructure and describe more specifically what stands for "not send back any response"